# Library to link for net-snmp mib parsing

Tags: net-snmp

I am trying to parse a MIB to my sub agent in Linux environment. However the parser code is not working fine. Do I need to link any static/dynamic library for MIB parsing.

I am referring to code from this link which is meant for windows platform : [net-snmp sample code to parse MIB file and extract trap related information from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330168/net-snmp-sample-code-to-parse-mib-file-and-extract-trap-related-information-from)

Kindly suggest If I am missing some library to get mib parsing work.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=slibsmi&oq=slibsmi&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3255j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=libsmi&spell=1

Comment: and https://www.google.co.in/search?q=slibsmi&oq=slibsmi&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3255j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=net-snmp

Comment: You are looking for net-snmp and libsmi